# R cannot be resolved to a variable in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I followed the instruction in 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond, however I receive a error that R cannot be resolved to a variable. I tried instead to import R by using import android.R; but it seems that once I did that activity_main,main, action_search and action_setting became "cannot be resolved or is not a field." Not sure where I went wrong.

```
package com.miracle.forth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
        //Handle presses on the action bar items 
        switch (item.getItemId())  {
          case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
          case R.id.action_settings:
            openSetting();
            return true;
        default:
            return super .onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openSearch() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openSetting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to import your own resource file. But I'm guessing you have an error on your res folder, that's why your R cannot be resolved.

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't invalid characters in your resource file names, such as numbers, Capitals, hyphens, ...? And also, double check ALL your xml files for the tiniest error/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that R.java belongs to the package namespace com.miracle.forth.However if the package names  are not same then you have to import com.miracle.forth.R.

If the java file and R.java belongs to the same package namespace then clean your project and restart eclipse.

Also check your xml files.If there are any errors in your xml file then R.java will not generate.

Comment: found the problem where the error is coming from but not sure what is wrong the res/menu/main.xml file showed no error except for the console showing error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Comment: Well after correcting my spelling error, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the naming convation

you capitalized or number in image name which you put in Drawble-mdpi or hdpi  folder
 you use first latter capital in  .xml file

first correct this mistake then new R file will generate and error will remove

Comment: I checked and found that I have a spelling mistakes in some .xml file but is still unable to generate R file. I believe the problem is in res/menu/main.xml The file itself does not contain any error but the console shows error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Comment: delete expect id from the file -- res/menu/main.xml

Comment: Well after correcting my spelling error, I solved the problem.